# how to get data from all subcollection firstore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I want to call data from all onsite collection

[image: i want to call data from all onsite collection]

i want to get data from all onsite collection. this is my coding

```
export class FirebaseService {
  onsiteRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<Onsiteinterface>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, public ngFireAuth: AngularFireAuth)  { 
    this.onsiteRef = db.collection('users/UjPaVdJ31ZNcnbJCcgDyZ1HJjUz2/onsite');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is known as a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). These operations read/query all collections with a specific name, no matter at what path in the data store they exist.

So to read from all `onsite` (sub)collections, you'd use:

```
this.onsiteRef = db.collectionGroup('onsite');
```